# Sticky notification (persistent) that remains in pull down notification list - Android and IOS ideally using JS framework

Tags: javascript, android, ios, frameworks, notifications

I would like to create a sticky notification that sits in the pull down notfication list (ie. will remain even if clear is pressed) for both IOS and Android is this possibe? and I would like to do this ideally using one of the many JS frameworks available can anyone recommend a framework in which this would be achievable?

This would give me a heads up whether I should look into developing an idea that I have for an app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On iOS it is not possible to make a persistent notification as the system/user sets a maximum amount of notifications (usually 5) and also the user can choose to clear the list for your app at anytime. This behaviour cannot be overridden.

Comment: Is this still valid?